# How to set http proxy filter?

Tags: proxy

I have an http proxy, which works OK, but there are some address on my lan which provides some web services.

I want to configure my device so that for some range of addresses the proxy is bypassed.

I have tried with 10.0.0.0/8, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Could you add what device you're using? At this point I'm not confident it's related to ICS.

Comment: Acer Iconia A500. And yes, the firmware is not (yet) official. I'll update this question when the official ICS firmware is released.

Comment: Have you tried 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it understands ranges in that notation, have you tried `10.*` or `10.*.*.*`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It doesn't understand 10.* or 10.*.*.* (the "save" button is disabled)

Comment: It seems to accept `10.0-254`, can't test it now since my current connection doesn't use a proxy. If you test it, let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly. Oh, and try `10.0-254.0-254.0-254` style too.

Comment: It accept these settings, but still it doesn't work! At this point I believe it's a firmware bug.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the firmware vendor has modified the [function which checks the proxy bypass list](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/jellybean/core/java/android/net/ProxyProperties.java#L101), specifying IP address ranges in the list is not possible — all entries are compared like domain names. Also the `*` wildcard is not supported, but is implied at the start of the domain name, as answered [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/33796/11251) (still valid even for JB).

So, if you want to use the builtin proxy support, you either need to list all required IP addresses explicitly, or, if your LAN has a DNS server, and all local servers are under some domain (`server.lan.example.com` or `server.local`), add that domain (`lan.example.com` or `local` for my examples) into the proxy bypass list, then access local servers using DNS names instead of raw IP addresses.

Alternatively, if you have a rooted phone, you can install a third-party proxy app such as [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid) or [Autoproxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mgranja.autoproxy); they should be more configurable than the builtin proxy support code.