# Wildcards in proxy bypass list

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi, proxy

My LG LS840 Viper 4G LTE (Sprint) recently upgraded to 4.0/ICS. Under 2.3/GB the proxy settings had been disabled entirely, but I am now able to set up per-network proxy settings for the various WiFi networks I attach to. Except—

Is there a way to add wildcards to the proxy bypass list? On (say) “Work WiFi” I can add `example.com` to the proxy bypass list, but not `*.example.com`. If any of the entries in the list have an asterisk, the Save button is disabled.

Is this a limitation in Android, or one which Sprint & LG have imposed on me? Is there a work-around?

ETA: A coworker running into a similar issue wit Cyanogenmod suggested `.example.com` (leading dot, no asterisk); this work-around works for him, but my phone rejects this form as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this CyanogenMod source code](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/ics/core/java/android/net/ProxyProperties.java#L85) (which, according to the [file history](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/commits/ics/core/java/android/net/ProxyProperties.java), does not actually have any CyanogenMod-specific changes), I see that the initial dot in proxy bypass list elements is just ignored, and an initial wildcard is implied — that is, you can write either `example.com` or `.example.com` in the list, and this entry will match `example.com`, `a.example.com`, `a.b.example.com`, … (note that any number of subdomain levels can be matched, unlike, e.g., with `*.example.com` in an SSL certificate).

If your phone does not actually work this way (e.g., you add `example.com` to the proxy bypass list, but `www.example.com` still goes through the proxy), either this code was modified by the phone vendor, or a particular app is using its own implementation of bypass list matching instead of the system-provided code.