# Add proxy exception for local subnet on Android 4.2 (4.* maybe ?)

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, internet, nexus-4, proxy

I'm using  Vanilla Android 4.2.2 on my Nexus4, and I'm using a proxy to access the internet. I wanted to add a proxy exception for addresses on my local subnet 192.168.0.* , is there anyway to do this?

I've tried adding 192.168.0 and this doesn't work, It doesn't accept 192.168.0.*, 192.168.0.0/8 and 192.168.0.255 doesn't work either.

Has anyone attempted this before? Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: A similar question [was already answered here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/46169/11251) — apparently there is no way to configure proxy exceptions for IP address ranges when using the builtin proxy support.

Comment: That's just sad. I was hoping android to be more configurable. Maybe the android market has an application. Could you please put your comment up as answer so that I can select close the question?

Comment: Have you tried adding it as 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.100 or whatever other range you want?

Answer (score -1):

Certainly you cannot enter the beginning and the ending address, so probably you can try entering all the ip address from beginning to end

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what I want to do. Not when I can have 10+ devices running on my local subnet, each of which changes its IP when the router reboots.